# Integral inequality : a distance function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $p>1$ , for $z \in\mathbb{C}- \mathbb{R+}$, defne $d(z,\mathbb{R+})=inf \{|z-x| ,x \in \mathbb{R+}\}$.
Let $f(z)=\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{|x-z|^p} dx$ , prove that there exist a constant $C_p$ such that :
$$f(z) \leq \frac{C_p}{d(z,\mathbb{R+})^{p+1}}$$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R+}$

I tried integration by parts by writing $z=a+ib$ ,bounding all terms but i don't have something near to the given bound. Any ideas?

Comment: I could be mistaken, but it seems $d(z,\mathbb{R}^+) = \sqrt{(\Im z)^2 + (\min\{ 0, \Re z\})^2}$, which would allow you to split into cases depending on $\Re z$.

Comment: I think your estimate should be with $p-1$ power not $p+1$ - eg let $p=2$, $z=1+iy, y >1,  \frac{1}{|x-z|^2} \ge  \frac{1}{2y^2}, 0 \le x \le y+1$, so $f(z) \ge  \frac{y+1}{2y^2} \ge 1/(2y)$ while $d(z,\mathbb{R+})=y$ so no way you can have $f(z) \le C/y^3$ for large $y$ - incidentally the above can easily be modified to get a proof for the estimate with $p-1$